# Xcode doesn't recognize files that are inside groups, so all view controllers have to be kept at the project root

Tags: xcode, storyboard, group

I love grouping my files in Xcode for convenience, but my Xcode has a bug that no one else seems to have. Let's say I have six screens in my project and a controller file for each. If I take half of these controllers and put them in a group, my project breaks. I can no longer add IBOutlets or IBActions to these files, including with odd work-arounds. Pulling up the assistant editor yields the empty gray screen when nothing is selected. If I delete the screen's reference to these files under their identity inspector tab, and type it again, Xcode no longer auto-fills the names. It's as if the file has completely disappeared from the project. If I run the project, it crashes.

I have run into a similar issue where I duplicated a storyboard view controller and assigned it to a new file, but forgot to break the connections it had with the previous file. This would cause the same thing to happen. So whatever causes this issue when I move view controller files to a group could very well be because I'm inexperienced.

Has anyone experienced this issue, and if so, been able to resolve it?